# PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small when running query multiple times

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I've got a webapp in Java EE, and sometimes in logs I see the following error:

```
`org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException`: 
 Error querying database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small"
```

I turned on the statements logging and if I run the query from SQL Developer it runs successfully, without any errors.

However, if I run the same query a few times I got this error. I guess the cause is on the DB server, any ideas?

Comment: it looks like that your resulting text exceed the declared length of your variable

Comment: As there's no code or, for that matter, information, in this post beyond an error message, I'm going to go out on a limb and say you need a bigger buffer. If you'd like a more informative answer, however, you're probably going to need to provide more information about the problem. Stack trace and code would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You need to trace the session to get the exact sql statement and bind variables to see what caused the error.  Set the following in your code at connection to create the trace file on the database server.

alter session set events '10046 trace name context forever, level 8';